# Можно ли через input вывести данные? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
isthatfinaldecision1 = input("Вы ввели",answer1,"будете менять? Да\нет")
```

Или все же придется через

```
print ("Вы ввели",answer1)
isthatfinaldecision1 = input("будете менять? Да\нет")
```

??

Comment: `input(f"Вы ввели {answer1}, будете менять? Да\нет")`

Comment: что такое f в данном случае?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
isthatfinaldecision1 = input("Вы ввели {}, будете менять? Да\нет".format(answer1))
```

или используя [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (для Python 3.6+):

```
isthatfinaldecision1 = input(f"Вы ввели {answer1}, будете менять? Да\нет")
```

Comment: Спасибо. А то через print коряво выходит.